# Change page after submitting the form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that after submitting goes to page "http://qwertyasdfgh.rozblog.com/New_Post" ( the action value )

I don't want to change the action but I want to redirect to another page after submitting.

I tried to redirect to "http://qwerty.rozblog.com/page/success" after submitting but it doesn't work .

here is the code I tried :

(html)

```
<form method="post" action="http://qwertyasdfgh.rozblog.com/New_Post" id="f1">
      <input type="text" name="title" style="width:300px"><br />
      <input type="text" name="pimg" style="width:300px" maxlength="3072"><br />
      <textarea dir="rtl" id="post" name="post" style="width:300px;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name="postsubmit" value=" submit " style="background:#333;" onclick="location()">
    </form>
```

(js)

```
 function location() {
   window.location.replace("http://qwerty.rozblog.com/page/success");
}
```

[and here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcLve/)

Comment: You can not do that. You are trying to make the page do two actions, it can only do one.

Comment: no way changing the page we redirect to while we have the action ?

Comment: and sorry if I speak English terrible :D

Comment: Unless the form opens up in a new window, no it is not possible. Normally you do the redirection on the form submission page. Other option is using Ajax to submit.

Comment: > no way changing the page we redirect to while we have the action ?

nope, but you could redirect to /success once the page /New_Post loaded, if that'd help

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form using [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and AJAX (or I misunderstood you):

```
$('#f1').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('http://qwertyasdfgh.rozblog.com/New_Post',
           formDataAsJSON, //use eg. jquery form plugin
           function(data)
           {
               window.location = 'somewhere';
           }
    );
});
```

Comment: Why would you use a plugin when built in `.serialize()` does it? `$( this ).serialize();`

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

1) Submit that form using AJAX and after recieving response from server redirect browser to your desired page. You can use for example jQuery with Ajax form plugin. The code would look like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'f1' form and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#f1').ajaxForm(function() { 
                window.location = "/page/success" 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

OR

2) You can leave your form and js as is, and use for example php to redirect user after doing some stuff.

New_post.php

```
<?php
// some stuff without printing (you cant change headers if you print something)

Header("Location: /page/success");
```

Comment: My pleasure. Please don't forget to select right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can configure /New_Post to redirect to /page/success using [meta refreshing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) in `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://qwerty.rozblog.com/page/success">
```