# PHP Redirect to new page after form submission

Tags: php, redirect, curl, action

I have a form, which redirects the user to "page1.php" after the form is submitted. What I want to do is to redirect the user to "page2.php" after the form is submitted, but I need to make sure that the POST request was sent. Example:

```
<form action="page1.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

When the user clicks on Submit, it redirects him to page1.php. I want to redirect him to page2.php, but I need to make sure that the data is sent to the server. I can't use AJAX. Is there any way to do it with cURL or something like that? Any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Use conditional statements.

Comment: Use a header() to redirect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change page after submitting the form using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703542/change-page-after-submitting-the-form-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this works !!
In page1.php

```
<?php
//do establish session
//and check for the input fields obtained via $_POST
if(isset($_POST['name_of_your_field']) && !empty($_POST['name_of_your_field'])){
    if(!mail($to,$subject,$message)){
        header('location:form.php?msg=error');  
    }else{
        header('location:page2.php?msg=succes');
        }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the POST request was sent with something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // do something...
}
```

You can create a hidden input in your form and send additional info about the form that is submitted, e.g. action.

Inside you will do your magic and redirect user with:

```
header('Location: page2.php');
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'page1.php' processor, add a 'header' redirect to 'page2.php'.

```
header("Location: page2.php");
exit;
```

Comment: This will cause double redirection. Submit page -> Page1 -> Page2. It has to be done with 1 redirect.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you can only have one redirect, then make your form post to `form2.php` and then in `form2.php`, you can send the form information to `form1.php` via cURL and then wait for the response back saying that it was accepted before proceeding with the code on `form2.php`.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a check if query is complete

example

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query(".......your query statement")or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
if($query){
           header("Location:page2.php");
          }
else{
     die('error');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you can just simple check for the posted data. Like

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
if($username&&$age){ /* This is to check if the variables are not empty  */
 // redirect to page2
}
```

It is logical that if those are not empty, meaning they are posted. Even if they are empty, as long as you get there, that means it was posted. There is no need to check if posted or not, what needs to be checked was, if posted data was there.

I hope I made it clear. ^_^ but making sure is not bad at all. Happy coding friend.